# Change Nuxt Route Without Re-rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a Nuxt page and i want to change route path without re-rendering or refreshing page with a method on a button.

if i do `this.$router.push()` or `replace()`, page will refresh and if i do `window.history.pushState()` or `replaceState()` that works fine but after that if i add a query with `this.$router.push({ query: a = b })` on my page, page will refresh because changing route with `window.history` will not change `$route` and when i use `this.$router.push`, Vue Router thinks its a different page.

I've done a lot of search on internet and did not find anything, so please don't label this question as duplicate.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with all of this?

Comment: i have some tabs in my page and im tring to sync active tab name in route

Comment: `router.push` doesn't refresh the page. Who told you it does?

Comment: If you're having tabs, try to use the dynamic component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: You don't even need to mess up with the router/path to achieve some tabs. Pass it regular props defining which tab to display.

Comment: Also, could you please provide us some code? Would be helpful to see what you're tying to do. Even a [repro] could be nice!

Comment: i know do not need to change path to active tab. but i want to keep tabs and route synce so if someone come in my page can go on any tab directly.
look this page to undrestand what im trying to do
https://www.beatstars.com/raspo/feed

Comment: go to https://www.beatstars.com/raspo/feed and try changing tabs and you see page URL is changing too but no refreshing or re-rendering happend

Comment: i have a page like this but if i change tab with $router.push() or $router.replace() tab content will be shown on click then page will be refreshed

Comment: router.push does not trigger a page *reload* if that's what you're talking about. 
If you mean that you're *router-view* changes then yeah of course it does. You're pushing a different route so of course the view will change.
If you *only* want to have the Tab change then the Tab should be a child of some Route (in the website you linked that'd be the root / ).
The website you linked basically does the same. you click a tab, it pushes a route and the tab gets rendered in its container accordingly.
Maybe [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) will help you too.

Comment: As mentioned above by @braks, when you navigate thanks to the Vue router (the one also used in Nuxt), you will remove some pages and mount some other instead. You can prevent this kind of behavior and have something more hacky but your use-case is totally classic. Hence you can use the default behavior of the nested pages. There is no "browser" refresh as in a F5 keypress. But there is a new rendering, otherwise you won't be able to get the fresh new components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're actually looking for is a Default Layout and some nested routes. Here is an example on how to achieve this in Nuxt with just a few steps: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing-nested-pages

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved this problem with using parent page and nuxt childs, i changed tabs to nav and rendered base components on parent page and other things on child pages and now it works fine. Tnx to @kissu and @Braks.